# Segregating and pushing Logs into different indices in elasticsearch using logstash based on loglevels

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, architecture, logstash

I am new to ELK stack and currently i want to push logs in different elasticsearch indices based on their loglevels. For example lets say logstash-error_logs index will contain only error logs (logs with loglevel as ERROR), logstash-ok_logs index will contain all INFO logs ()logs with loglevel as INFO ) and so on. Given is the format of my logfile:

> [2016-01-06 13:29:49] staging.INFO: Callback sent

Hence the grok filter i am using is as given below:

```
grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424SD} %{JAVACLASS:LOGLEVEL}" }
    }
```

This provides me an additional field of "LOGLEVEL" in the JSON of the logs . Using this field I can use conditions to route the logs to different indices depending upon the loglevel. Hence I am using the following code in the output filter to route the logs accordingly:

```
output {
    if [LOGLEVEL] in  ["staging.ERROR"] {
            elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                            index => "logstash-error_logs"
            }
    }
    else if [LOGLEVEL] in  ["staging.INFO"] {
            elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                            index => "logstash-ok_logs"
            }
    }
    else {
            elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                            index => "tech"
            }
    }
    stdout {    codec =>     rubydebug }
```

}

But unfortunately staging. INFO logs are not getting routed to required index.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. "in" is more for tags.  Try this:

   if [LOGLEVEL] == "staging.ERROR" {
       ...
   }
2. rather than repeating your output stanzas with a small difference in between them, set and use a variable (Note: pseudo-code; I always get the => syntax wrong):

   if [LOGLEVEL] == "staging.ERROR" {
       mutate {
           add_field => { "index_name" => "error" }
       }
   }

and then in your output:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{index_name}_logs"
    }
}
```

If you don't want the "index_name" field to be sent to elasticsearch, you can put it in @metadata instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. I have already tried the first approach but this is not working . I don;t get the reason why even after having a LOGLEVEL field in the JSON of the logs we cannot do  if [LOGLEVEL] == "staging.ERROR" { ... } !!!!                                                                                                            2. can you elaborate the second approach more . I mean do i need to add the variable in the filter {...} plugin ???

Comment: further while going with the first approach the control is not going to the else part too!!!!!!! the logs are getting routed not to the tech department as they should have but to the "logstash-*" index that i have not mentioned in my config file !!!!!!!!! can you explain this unexpected behavior ???

Comment: In the second approach, the conditional mutate would be in the filter block.  It sets a variable ("index_name") which is then referenced in the output block.

Comment: When you see unexpected behavior, look for an old config file in the same directory.  Logstash loads them all!

Comment: i am changing the config file each and every time i am bringing any change to my config file and i m restarting the logstash . So why would logstash load the old config file ??? And even if it is what can be done to prevent logstash from doing it ??

Comment: Alain now I believe that the problem is not with my code or something but it is with some settings . This is because the logs are getting routed to "logstash-*" index each and everytime . So do you have any idea about any such setting that can be the reason for this ???

Comment: hey Alain the first approach is working . Actually the problem was with kibana it is still not showing the result in its interface . But when i am querying the index using the postman app it is showing the logs in it . Any idea about why it is so ? Further now the new problem is in the output plugin by doing- if [loglevel] == "staging.ERROR" or "production.ERROR"{ .....} , logs with staging.ERROR are only getting into the index but the logs with production.ERROR are not getting in the indices. can you tell why so ??

Comment: Hey Alain , now i am sure the logs are getting into their desired indices as i checked this using POSTMAN app . But kibana is now showing those logs when i m viewing them in kibana by choosing the "error_logs" . I strongly feel that there is some problem with kibana index settings .....help me with this !!!!!!

Comment: Hey Alain , the problem has been sorted out . The problem was not in the code but was in the kibana index configuration . This is why logs were not showing in the index . Its working cool now ;)